# How can I make vertical switch

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS, but I have an idea on JavaScript.

Previously, I made a horizontal switch in the following way using flat-ui from [flat-ui](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/)

[image]

Now I want to implement vertical switch in the following way

[image]

How can I make it?

Comment: Give your code here which u have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
    <ul class="body">
    <li >
        <a>switch #1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a>switch #2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

See the css and animation in link

[jsfiddle.net/uNFWX/](http://jsfiddle.net/uNFWX/)

Comment: In the same I stuck to make horizontal `collapse`.`BootStrap 3.0` not supporting for horizontal `collapse`. So can you give me any suggestion.